# I can't install the package quick.db

Tags: node.js, npm, quick.db

I'm new to this platform and new to coding so please be kind :3
maybe it's just a dumb error or something, :|

This is what happens when I use "npm i quick.db" to install the package.

If it's a code error please tell me :3 it says something about visual studio, do i need to download anything?

````
> better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install C:\Users\G752V\Desktop\discord-levelling-bot-master\node_modules\better-sqlite3
> prebuild-install || npm run build-release

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.16.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

> better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release C:\Users\G752V\Desktop\discord-levelling-bot-master\node_modules\better-sqlite3
> node-gyp rebuild --release


C:\Users\G752V\Desktop\discord-levelling-bot-master\node_modules\better-sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1440) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\G752V\Desktop\discord-levelling-bot-master\node_modules\better-sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release: `node-gyp rebuild --release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\G752V\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-18T17_19_37_269Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install: `prebuild-install || npm run build-release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\G752V\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-18T17_19_37_407Z-debug.log```
````